# npm run doesn't pass --configuration to build task

Tags: angular, docker, npm, dockerfile, angular-cli

I'm having trouble running `ng build` command from `npm run`. I have the following scenarios:

- When I build my project on my local enviroment I run `ng build --configuration=development` and everything works fine.
- On the other hand, When I build my Docker Image I run the command using `npm rum ng build --configuration=$VAR` and the param isn't be passed and the result isn't the expected.

Although I think that is not necessary, my Dockerfile is below

```
# STAGE 1: Build
##############################################################################

# Image
FROM node:10-alpine as builder
MAINTAINER joseantonio@gogroup.es

# BUILD ARGS
ARG ENVIROMENT

# Installing GIT & Bash
RUN apk add --no-cache git

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
RUN mkdir /pancho-ui
RUN mv ./node_modules ./pancho-ui
WORKDIR /pancho-ui
COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN npm run ng build --output-path=dist --configuration=$ENVIROMENT --verbose

# STAGE 2: Setup
##############################################################################

# Image
FROM nginx:1.14.1-alpine
MAINTAINER joseantonio@gogroup.es

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From ‘builder’ stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /pancho-ui/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN mv /usr/share/nginx/html/pancho-ui/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

# Run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of my problem in this [post](https://jurosh.com/blog/npm-pass-parameters-into-script).

My sintax of `npm run` wasn't correct. The correct way to pass params to a `npm` command is adding `--` operator.

In my case I need to change

```
RUN npm run ng build --output-path=dist --configuration=$ENVIROMENT --verbose
```

to

```
RUN npm run ng build -- --output-path=dist --configuration=$ENVIROMENT --verbose
```

Comment: +10 if I could. that -- got me.

Comment: totally forgot, thx!